# Preencher input2 a partir do input1?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Tenho o "input1" que busca o nome de um cliente e salva seu id na tabela, essa busca é feita pelo autocomplete com JavaScript.

Agora precisava que no "input2" recebesse o id do "parceiro" vinculado ao id do cliente que foi inserido no "input1", ambos pertencem a mesma tabela (cliente e parceiro).

Não é necessário mostrar o nome do parceiro no form, apenas salvar seu id correspondente ao id do cliente que já é exibido.

A exibição da tabela com a coluna cliente e parceiro está OK, testei com inserção do id parceiro direto no BD, só não consigo pelo form.

```
<div class="control-group">
 <label for="clientes" class="control-label">Cliente</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <input id="cliente"  type="text" name="cliente"  />
      <input id="clientes_id" type="hidden" name="clientes_id" value=""/>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cliente").autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/exportacao/autoCompleteCliente",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
             $("#clientes_id").val(ui.item.id);
        }
  });    
}
```

Controller: Exportacao.php

```
public function autoCompleteCliente(){
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){ //devolve indice referente ao nome do cliente
        $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
        $this->fatexpo_model->autoCompleteCliente($q);
    }        
}
```

model: fatexpo_model.php

```
 public function autoCompleteCliente($q){
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->limit(5);
     $this->db->like('nomeCliente', $q);//busca pelo nome do cliente
     $query = $this->db->get('clientes');
     if($query->num_rows() > 0){
         foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
             $row_set[] = array('label'=>$row['nomeCliente'],'id'=>$row['idClientes']);
         }
         echo json_encode($row_set);
     }
 }
```

[image: Autocomplete do form]

Na imagem, o input armazena o id = 7 correspondente ao nome Bridgestone, o seu parceiro seria id = 2

Tudo está funcionando, consigo fazer os cadastros e exibi-los, só não consigo salvar o id parceiro vinculado ao id cliente que já pego.

Comment: Sua pergunta tá confusa, vamos por partes: você tem no banco de dados vários clientes (que é o que está sendo buscado por autocomplete) e cada um destes clientes têm um campo `parceiroId`, certo?

Comment: Olá, desculpe, não consegui ser mais específico.
Isso, tenho uma tabela "clientes": idClientes, nomeCliente e parceiros_id.
O parceiros_id armazena o id de outra tabela "parceiros": idParceiros, nomeParceiro e cnpj.

Meu form armazena os dados em uma terceira tabela "exportacao".
Obrigado pela disposição em ajudar.

Comment: O id do parceiro já vem no autocomplete?

Comment: Certo, @MatheusMadalozzo Dito isso, vamos pro próximo passo: o que você pretende é: ao selecionar um **cliente** que mostre, além do nome, no campo abaixo o valor de `parceiros_id`?

Comment: @LINQ isso, eu precisava pegar o valor de parceiros_id para salvá-lo na minha terceira tabela "exportacao" em "parceiro_expo". O id do cliente eu já armazeno nessa tabela exportacao.

Comment: @DvD não amigo, somente o idClientes.

Comment: @MatheusMadalozzo Veja minha resposta.

Comment: @LINQ excelente, vou tentar e lhe retorno assim que possível.

Comment: @LINQ caso resolvido! Excelente ajuda, muito obrigado pela solução, disponibilidade e agilidade!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você precisa fazer é adaptar a função `autoCompleteCliente` para retornar — além de `idClientes` e `nomeCliente` — o campo `parceiros_id`.

```
public function autoCompleteCliente($q){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $this->db->like('nomeCliente', $q);//busca pelo nome do cliente
    $query = $this->db->get('clientes');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $row_set[] = array('label' => $row['nomeCliente'], 
                               'id' => $row['idClientes'], 
                               'parceiroId' => $row['parceiros_id']);
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set);
    }
}
```

Depois, é necessário adaptar a função JavaScript que é disparada assim que um elemento do *autocomplete* é selecionado, fazendo com que o valor recebido em `ui.item.parceiroId` seja inserido em algum input. Como você não especificou este input na pergunta, deixei como exemplo o seletor **`#parceiro_id`**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cliente").autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/exportacao/autoCompleteCliente",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#clientes_id").val(ui.item.id);
            $("#parceiro_id").val(ui.item.parceiroId);
        }
    });    
}
```

Com estas modificações, você vai conseguir ver o valor do campo `parceiros_id` no input.